# Can't return a function with default parameter values

Tags: swift, function

There is a function is nested in a function, the inner function with default parameter values, jut like this:

```
let myStr = returnStr()
func returnStr() -> (String) -> (){
    var str = "hello"
    func innerFunc(s: String = "test"){
        str += s
        print(str)
    }
    return innerFunc
}
```

I can invoke `myStr("world")`, but can't invoke `myStr()` with default parameter value. Is this right? I didn't find any documents say it's not support return function with default parameter values.
When invoke `myStr()`, there is an error "Missing argument fro parameter #1 in call".
Is there a way to make these two use work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the signature of `innerFunc` is `String->Void`

whenever you declare `let x = innerFunc`. `x` will always be `String->Void` type.

When you provide default parameters, it will not generate another type like `Void->Void`,

---

For example

```
func sayHello(name: String, to otherName: String = "my self", excited: Bool = false){
    // do something
}

let x = sayHello // x is (String, to: String, excited: Bool) -> Void
```